# VBA runtime error 3625 The text file specification Export_Spec does not exist

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am running Access 2016. I am trying to export the results of a query into a text file, I keep on getting an error 3625 no spec is found. I created the spec and if I run the spec it works as expected. I tried putting quotes instead of the export spec, but there was no formatting on the file. The solutions I found on the web were saying to use the advanced tab to define formatting, On my version of Access 2016 there is no advanced tab in the spec creation process. I have stepped through the process and all the directories and the file name is created properly.
The error occurs on the line :
DoCmd.TransferText TransferType:=acExportDelim, SpecificationName:=strExportSpec, TableName:=strQueryName, FileName:=strFullName, HasFieldNames:=True

[image: Spec Description]

Any help is appreciated.

```
Private Sub Export_Click()
Dim strFileName As String
Dim lFileName As Long
Dim strCurrentDate As String
Dim strFormattedDate As String
Dim dtCurrentDate As Date
Dim strDir As String
Dim strFullName As String
Dim strExportSpec As String
Dim strQueryName As String
Dim strYear As String
Dim strMonth As String
Dim strPath1 As String
Dim strPath2 As String


strYear = Format(Date, "yyyy")
strMonth = Format(Date, "mm")

'Check if Directory Year exists
strPath1 = "C:\Users\Owner\Google Drive\Employment\Mass Unemployment\" & strYear


'Check if year exists
If Dir(strPath1, vbDirectory) = "" Then
    MkDir strPath1
End If
'Create

strPath2 = "C:\Users\Owner\Google Drive\Employment\Mass Unemployment\" & strYear & "\" & strMonth & "\"

If Dir(strPath2, vbDirectory) = "" Then
    MkDir strPath2
End If

strCurrentDate = Date
strFormattedDate = Format(strCurrentDate, "mmddyyyy")
lFileName = InputBox("Enter Week Number", "Enter Week Number")

strFileName = strFormattedDate
strFullName = strPath2 & strFileName & ".txt"
strExportSpec = "Export_Spec"    ' error 3625 export spec does not exist
strQueryName = "qryUnEmployment"

DoCmd.TransferText TransferType:=acExportDelim, SpecificationName:=strExportSpec, TableName:=strQueryName, FileName:=strFullName, HasFieldNames:=True 
 
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what Parfait is telling you is that the Saved Import/Saved Exports are far different than an Import/Export Specification.  You are trying to put a Saved Export into the TransferText parameter where a Specification is called for. You likely did an export at some point and saved the steps as a Saved Export.

If you're truly interested in using a specification for this export then you will want to create one by walking through the import of an already existing text file in the format you would like.  See Parfait answer above.

Otherwise, just leave the specification parameter blank and the query will be exported.

Answer (score 0):

The [Save Import/Export](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/run-a-saved-import-or-export-specification-6969e099-4573-40f0-a1e0-f3042bddb640) GUI frontend feature and the backend method, [DoCmd.TransferText](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.docmd.transfertext) refer to different specification types. The former is more a saved *routine* as a convenience method to retrieve the same named text, spreadsheet, or XML file and all the steps to import or export the external data and avoid the walk through of wizard in future runs.

However, the latter is specific to formatting of *any* text file and it is usually created during the text file wizard under **Advanced** button. See screenshot below. In this dialog you can specify formats for each field, delimiters, etc. and then either run the specification one time or `Save As...` for future uses on *any* text file. In fact, `Specs...` shows a current list of all saved named specifications. It is here where you can find the name to use in `DoCmd.TransferText`.

**Import Text  Wizard**

[image: Import Text File Specs Screenshot]

**Export Text Wizard**

[image: Export Text File Specs Screenshot]

To date, there may not be any other GUI way to adjust these saved specifications. They are stored in system tables, `MSysIMEXspecs` and `MSysIMEXColumns`. Again, do not confuse above text file specific method for the generalized external data methods: [ImportExportSpecifications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Access.ImportExportSpecifications) and [DoCmd.RunSavedImportExport](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.docmd.runsavedimportexport#:%7E:text=This%20method%20has%20the%20same%20effect%20as%20performing,that%20you%20want%20to%20...%203%20Select%20Run.).

Comment: But I want to export a file based on a query not import it. The export function does not have an advanced feature on it. So how would I use the export function? I can put quotes where the spec is located but then the formatting of the file is messed up.

Comment: Hmmm...there is an Advanced button on the Export Text Wizard. See added screenshot above. Which version of Access are you using? Be sure to have table/query opened or selected in Navigation Pane.